# Update Unique for One Field in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

A user collection has an array of sites. Each site has a name. I wish that all site names will be unique per user.

user-1 with two sites called "a" and "b", and user-2 with a site called "a" is ok. But user-1 with two sites called "a" and "a" is not ok.

Here is an attempt to update a site's name but only if it's unique per user. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
collection.update({ 
    _id: userId, 
    'sites._id' : req.params.id, 
    'sites' : {$not : {$elemMatch : {name: req.body.name}}}
    },                 
    { $set: { 'sites.$.name': req.body.name } });
```

Data example:

```
db.users.insert({
"_id" : ObjectId("59f1ebf8090f072ee17438f5"),
"email" : "user.email@gmail.com",
"sites" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59f5ebf8190f074ee17438f3"),
        "name" : "site 1"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59f5bbf8194f074be17438f2"),
        "name" : "site 2"
    }
]});
```

Comment: Does not work because you are also testing on `sites._id` which would be part of the same array element. So with `[{ "_id": 1, "name": "a" },{ "_id": 2, "name": "b" }]` then If you attempted to set `2` to `"a"` it would just do it since you only look at `2`. But if you simply `{ "sites.name": { "$ne": "a" } }` ( don't need `$elemMatch` for one condition ) then there is an `"a"` and it's perfectly fine. So what you are attempting to do does not make sense by including a unique identifier as part of the constraint for array testing. You want to look at all array elements without constraint.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. I try the same only with  `'sites.name' : { $ne : req.body.name }` instead of `'sites':....` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Short version. "just test the name". Testing the id has no place in your query. At least for "updating". Show the data if you still don't get it. Mind you, the problem is of course that you only get the "first" match. We can work around this in future MongoDB versions, but it could very well be a problem here. Show some data anyway, as there is another workaround to this that comes to mind. But seeing the data would verify it.

Comment: I must have the site.id because this query is supposed to update the name of a particular site that a particular user owns. The only thing is I want to check this new name he is submitting to make sure it is unique among his other sites.

Comment: Show some documents then please. Talking about it is going nowhere. Show what you have and then we can walk through it.

Comment: Ok I added data example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that you need to update by a specific `_id` value in the array but only where the `"name"` does not already exist in another element. The particular problem is the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and how that applies to using the "matched" element.

Point is you want the "position" from the `_id` but the other constraint on the whole array without actually affecting either the document match or the position.

You cannot use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) since the `"name"` test applies to ALL elements of the array, regardless of `_id`. And you cannot ["dot notate"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) both fields in the query, since the match conditions could be found on different positions. For example `"site 3"` is not matched on the **first** array element, but a provided `_id` value may be matched on the **second** array element.

Presently, the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) only works with the **first** match found. So what needs to happen at current is we can only really keep the position from the `_id` match, even though you still want a constraint looking for "unique" values within `"name"` which are not currently present in another before altering.

## Current MongoDB

The only way you currently get to keep the position but be able to test the array for not having the `"name"` is to use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) with a JavaScript expression which looks at the array. The trick being that the normal query conditions match the "position", but the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) affects document selection without having any effect on the "position" which is matched.

So trying to write `"site 2"` to the first array entry:

```
db.users.update(
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f1ebf8090f072ee17438f5"),
    "sites._id": ObjectId("59f5ebf8190f074ee17438f3"),
    "$where": '!this.sites.some(s => s.name === "site 2")'
  },
  {
    "$set": { "sites.$.name": "site 2" }   
  }
)
```

Updates nothing because the constraint of:

```
!this.sites.some(s => s.name === "site 2")
```

Shows that at least one of the array elements via [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) actually matched the criteria, so the document is rejected from update.

When you change to `"site 3"` on the second element:

```
db.users.update(
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f1ebf8090f072ee17438f5"),
    "sites._id": ObjectId("59f5bbf8194f074be17438f2"),
    "$where": '!this.sites.some(s => s.name === "site 3")'
  },
  {
    "$set": { "sites.$.name": "site 3" }   
  }
)
```

None of the array elements are matched by the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause, but of course the `_id` does so this position is used in the update. So the update applies correctly to the matched element and not just the "first element" which did not have the name:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59f1ebf8090f072ee17438f5"),
    "email" : "user.email@gmail.com",
    "sites" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59f5ebf8190f074ee17438f3"),
            "name" : "site 1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59f5bbf8194f074be17438f2"),
            "name" : "site 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

## MongoDB 3.6

From MongoDB 3.6 we can do this differently and not rely on JavaScript evaluation as a "workaround". The new addition is the [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operator which allows us to "turn around" those conditions as above and instead "query" natively on the `"name"` but "filter" on the `"_id"` value:

```
db.users.update(
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("59f1ebf8090f072ee17438f5"),
    "sites.name": { "$ne": "site 4" }
  },
  { "$set": { "sites.$[el].name": "site 4" } },
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "el._id": ObjectId("59f5bbf8194f074be17438f2") }]  }
)
```

So here we get the correct result of the second array element still being updated despite the query condition actually meeting a "first" match on the very first element of the array. This is because what takes over after the "document selection" from the query is how the `arrayFilters` are defined along with the positional filtered operator. Her we alias as `[el]` for the matched element from the `"sites"` array, and look for it's `_id` sub-property within the `arrayFilters` definition.

This actually makes a lot more sense to read and is easier to construct that a JavaScript statement representing the condition. So it's a really useful boon being added into MongoDB for updating.

## Conclusion

So right now, code using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to positionally match like this yet still put a constraint on the array. From MongoDB 3.6 this will be much easier to code and a bit more efficient since the document exclusion can be fully done in native code operators whilst still retaining a method for matching the position.